# Why does the `package` instruction in java make the class file impossible to run?

Tags: java, windows, package, classpath

I'm trying to compile a `java` file with a package directive.  However, when adding the directive to the most simple program stub, I get an error and cannot launch the program anymore... What's wrong ?

Dummy0:

```
class Dummy0 {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

Dummy1:

```
package de.train;

class Dummy1 {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

And here is the output I had.  Everything compiled fine.  But I cannot run the class de.train.Dummy1, although it's obviously there.

```
$ javac Dummy*.java
$ java Dummy0
Hello, world!
$ java Dummy1
Error: Could not find or load main class Dummy1
$ java de.train.Dummy1
Error: Could not find or load main class de.train.Dummy1
$ javap Dummy1.class
Compiled from "Dummy1.java"
class de.train.Dummy1 {
  de.train.Dummy1();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

I'm under windows for this project.  Is this some security restriction?  How to remove it?

Comment: If you're actually using Windows, why have you posted a Unix-like command output?

Comment: Oops, it's cygwin output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for the class `de.train.Dummy1`, which means it will look for a file called `Dummy1.class` in a directory `de\train` - but the file will *actually* be in the current directory.

Options:

- Keep your source code where it is, but get the compiler to generate the directory structure for you:

  ```
  > javac -d . Dummy*.java
  > java de.train.Dummy1
  ```
- Move `Dummy1.java` into a `de\train` directory:

  ```
  > javac de\train\Dummy*.java
  > java de.train.Dummy1
  ```

Comment: how to become a programmer like you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing a java program without packages it will try to locate the classes in the same folder/directory. Package is nothing but the directory structure in windows. If you want to execute a class in some other folder you have to specify the complete package and execute.